# Suspended (exception RuntimeException) When I click a button that opens a new class with a new layout

Tags: android, exception

My app recently started throwing a "Suspended (exception RuntimeException)" I think I might have accidentally messed with some code but I cant pinpoint the problem.

This is my log chat when I click on the breakfast button.

> 04-14 17:54:15.941: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6099): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   04-14 17:54:15.941: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6099): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.merch.dine/com.merch.dine.myMenu}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton
>   04-14 17:54:15.941: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6099):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2737)
>   04-14 17:54:15.941: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6099):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2753)
>   04-14 17:54:15.941: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6099):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:129)
>   04-14 17:54:15.941: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6099):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2107)
>   04-14 17:54:15.941: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6099):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   04-14 17:54:15.941: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6099):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
>   04-14 17:54:15.941: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6099):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4701)
>   04-14 17:54:15.941: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6099):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   04-14 17:54:15.941: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6099):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   04-14 17:54:15.941: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6099):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   04-14 17:54:15.941: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6099):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>   04-14 17:54:15.941: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6099):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   04-14 17:54:15.941: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6099): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton
>   04-14 17:54:15.941: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6099):     at com.merch.dine.myMenu.onCreate(myMenu.java:36)
>   04-14 17:54:15.941: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6099):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   04-14 17:54:15.941: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6099):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2701)

Here is the debug info on the thread

> Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))
>       ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2659
>       ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2753
>       ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 129
>       ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 2107
>       ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99
>       Looper.loop() line: 143
>       ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4701
>       Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]
>       Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521
>       ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 868
>       ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 626
>       NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]

here is my java file with the button that causes the crash

```
public class EnglishOne extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //FIXED LANDSCAPE
        setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); 

        //FULLSCREEN
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.english1);

        //button breakfast
        Button bBreakfast1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.breakfast1);

        bBreakfast1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View V) {
                startActivity(new Intent("com.merch.dine.BREAKFASTONE"));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the activity that the button should start with a blank xml layout

```
public class breakfastone extends Activity {

    public void OnCreate(Bundle breakfastone) {
        super.onCreate(breakfastone);
        setContentView(R.layout.breakfast1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I circumvented my problem by using XML to set the `onClick` function and then coded my java file to change the content view when the function is called.

Xml button specific code;

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_height="160dip"
    android:layout_width="285dip"
    android:onClick="switchLayer"
    android:src="@drawable/icon"
    android:layout_x="285dip"
    android:layout_y="481dip">
</ImageButton>
```

Java Button specific code;

```
public void switchLayer(View view) {
    // Button1 switches layout
    setContentView(R.layout.layer2);
}
```